# Can react js web code be used for building mobile apps using react native?

Tags: reactjs, web, react-native

I am working on a pet project ( web application ) and I was wondering if I should use react because it would be easy to create native apps from this code (in future if I need to).

- And if the answer is yes, what are the best practices to follow for
  most resuse?
- If the answer is no, can you recommend an alternative?

**Some more information about my situation.**

I am relatively new to react and my alternative will be good ol' html with bootstrap and jquery. I am considering using asp.net mvc and web api.

Comment: There's https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web, but it works the other way around..Build in React-Native and create the web pages later

Comment: It is possible. I'd suggest you to read [Sharing Code between React Web and Native Apps](http://jkaufman.io/react-web-native-codesharing/)

Comment: Like @atlanteh said, that framework exists.  React-Native doesn't have a "DOM" but the same components used in React Native can be created using a DOM.  (Browsers offer much more built-in rendering flexibility than what React Native components support)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sharing app logic between a React Web app and a React Native app, while keeping the individual component rendering unique to each platform is possible!

In my opinion, it is a great option we have available. I will give you an overview of the approach and a few advices.

In an ideal world, we would be able to share 100% of the code. As far as I know, that isn't possible, but still we can share a lot of the code. Although React Native is like React, it is very important to note that **the rendering code is different**. Instead web things like `<div>` or `<span>`, you use React Native components like `<View>`, `<Text>` and other built-in components.

However, the business logic in most cases is just JavaScript though and that's one of the important things which we can share!

## The plan

Based on the Flux architecture you are using, it would mean that your store(s), reducers, actions would be shared code, as well as most of the business logic (inside services or whatever) and the constants and utilities too.

**The UI layer would then be written specifically for each native platform using React Native and for web using React**. Not only because it’s necessary to replace the HTML elements with React Native components, but also because the components will probably have a very different behavior on the mobile app.

## Some General Guidelines / Advices

- Consider a good architecture and code structure in order to share as much code (and application logic) as possible. Try to separate the UI presentation components (which will be different for each platform).
- Take a look at the [JavaScript Environment specifics](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html) in the React Native docs. When using React Native, you're going to be running your JavaScript code in two environments:

  > - On iOS simulators and devices, Android emulators and devices. React Native uses JavaScriptCore which is the JavaScript engine that powers Safari. On iOS JSC doesn't use JIT due to the absence of writable executable memory in iOS apps.
  > - When using Chrome debugging, it runs all the JavaScript code within Chrome itself and communicates with native code via WebSocket. So you are using V8.

  While both environments are very similar, you may end up hitting some inconsistencies.
- Consider the different strategies for sharing the code. In order to accesses shared code, the apps you're building doesn't have to all live in the same codebase or git repository.

  More realistically, you would have two or more projects hosted separately, so an npm package is one of the easiest ways to share code between them.

  This is easy as making a new package and setting it as a dependency inside each of your projects. For the path to the shared project, you can use a git repository rather than pointing to a public package on npm.

  Even though you're building only the web app now, **you could spend some time thinking about how you could generalize some of the shared code**, so it is easier to re-use it in future.

Comment: This answers the question well but what's wrong with just re-using the ReactJs code for mobile instead of re-writing a bunch of stuff?

Comment: Thanks. This definitely helps

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson it is not possible because the rendering code is different for web and mobile. Instead web things like `<div>` or `<span>`, on mobile we use React Native components like `<View>`, `<Text>` and other built-in components that represent mobile-specific items.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible and viable. You must have a view for each platform (web/android/ios), because each one have your components..

The business logic must be out of the view. Use flux can easy your project with native, because the it move the api interaction to a data layer, letting the view be just a view.