# is it possible to transform React to React native?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

If I have a react based website, can I transform it to react native easily? Or should I build it as react native from day one?

Comment: The real problem is that `react-dom` is not compatible with native. You could (re)write your Web client using `react-native-web` and then you'd have a lot more re-use with native.

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41191135/1333836

Answer (score 1):

> If I have a react based website, can I transform it to react native
>   easily? Or should I build it as react native from day one?

No. There is no "magic-converter-thingamabob" you can use. But depending on your existing React code, and your specifications for the native app, you should be able to share some of the code-base between the apps.

The view part will have to be done from scratch. Not only because it’s necessary to replace the HTML elements with React Native components, but also because the components will probably have a very different behaviour on the mobile app [(source)](https://www.ckl.io/blog/sharing-code-reactjs-react-native/).

React Native has less of a "write once, run everywhere", and more of a **"learn once, write everywhere"** philosophy. [Here is an article with examples and github repo.](http://jkaufman.io/react-web-native-codesharing/)

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing your app's UI from scratch as this in line with Facebooks's “learn once, write anywhere” approach (https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/03/26/introducing-react-native.html).